# Handling tensorflow session in a class

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow to predict outputs of a neural network. I have a class where I have described the neural network and I have a main file where the predictions are being made, and based on the results, the weights are updated. However, the predictions seem to be really slow. Here is how my code looks like:

```
class NNPredictor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = tf.placeholder(...)
        ...
        self.output = (...) #Neural network output
    def predict_output(self, sess, input):
        return sess.run(tf.squeeze(self.output), feed_dict = {self.input: input})
```

Here's how the main file looks like:

```
sess = tf.Session()
predictor = NNPredictor()

input = #some initial value 
for i in range(iter):
    output = predictor.predict_output(sess, input)
    input = #some function of output
```

However, if I use the following function definition in the class:

```
    def predict_output(self):
        return self.output
```

And have the main file as follows:

```
sess = tf.Session()
predictor = NNPredictor()

input = #some initial value 
output_op = predictor.predict_value()
for i in range(iter):
    output = np.squeeze(sess.run(output_op, feed_dict = {predictor.input: input}))
    input = #some function of output
```

The code runs almost 20-30x faster. I don't seem to understand how things are working here, and I'd like to know what the best practice would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the underlying memory accesses masked by Python. Here's some sample code to illustrate this idea:

```
import time

runs = 10000000

class A:
    def __init__(self):
    self.val = 1

    def get_val(self):
    return self.val

# Using method to then call object attribute
obj = A()
start = time.time()
total = 0
for i in xrange(runs):
    total += obj.get_val()
end = time.time()
print end - start

# Using object attribute directly
start = time.time()
total = 0
for i in xrange(runs):
    total += obj.val
end = time.time()
print end - start

# Assign to local_var first
start = time.time()
total = 0
local_var = obj.get_val()
for i in xrange(runs):
    total += local_var
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

On my computer, it runs in the following timing:

```
1.49576115608
0.656110048294
0.551875114441
```

Specific to your case, you're calling the object method in the first case but not doing it in the second case. If you're calling your code many times in this way, there would be significant performance differences.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I do realize there might be a certain overhead associated with calling the object method, but here its too high. For instance, in a single iteration calling the object method takes 0.03s while without it, its usually 0.001-0.002s. Can all of it be only because of what you mentioned, or is there something else to it as well?

Comment: I didn't do the timings for a single object method call. But if your timings are correct, it's about 20x isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the code that I'm using is a bit different. The method over there is: `return tf.squeeze(self.output)`. At first, I thought its insignificant, but now I realize its slow because it creates a new node each time, which isn't the case in the other one

Comment: `predict_value()` function was not displayed as well. Perhaps you could add all relevant functions to your question so others can understand in future.